# How to properly use 離れる

Tags: translation, word-choice, usage

I'm trying to translate the sentence, "New York is over three hours away."

Right now I have, ニューヨークは３時間以上離れている。

Is what I have correct? Or is there a more natural way of saying this sentence? Looking at a few example sentences, I think 離れる is the right verb to use, but I'm unsure. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your sentence is understood, but it could feel ambiguous (time or distance?) and the listener may ask what you mean.

Most probably just use a different verb would be more common:

- ニューヨークまで3時間以上かかる
- ニューヨークまで3時間以上ある (this sounds you are on the way to NY)

or if you stick to 離れる

- ニューヨークは(車で/飛行機で)3時間以上離れたところにある.